# Read file for value, loop until value = $foo?

Tags: bash, loops

I'm writing a shell script that greps for `$foo` then counts the number of occurrences then runs a command. Each time that command is run, there is one less instance of $foo in that file. Uncertain on how to continuously read that file and reduce the value in the variable I set.

```
$count= `grep -o $foo /some/file |wc -w`

until [ $count -eq 0 ] 
do
  some_command_that_deletes_foo_in_file
done
```

However I realize that `$count` is set once at runtime and is not updated. What I want is `$count` to be updated to the current count in `/some/file` while the script is looping through /some/file until there is 0 instances of the phrase I'm grepping for. Uncertain to what the best approach is.

Comment: count=$(grep -c $foo /some/file )

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have additional code that you haven't showed us that depends on `$count`, you don't actually need to count occurrences; you just need to know whether the string appears in the file. For that, you can write:

```
while grep -q -- "$foo" /some/file ; do
  some_command_that_deletes_foo_in_file
done
```

(using the fact that `grep` returns success when it finds the value, and failure when it does not, and using the `-q` flag to suppress its console output).

Comment: The `-q` also causes it to stop reading the file after it returns a match, making this more efficient than counting.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the grep command inside the loop:

```
count=$(grep -o "$foo" /some/file |wc -w)

until (( count == 0 )) 
do
  some_command_that_deletes_foo_in_file
  count=$(grep -o "$foo" /some/file |wc -w)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to delete the string "$foo"? Use sed:

```
sed "/$foo/d" /some/file > /some/other/file
```

The `sed` command is an editor. The `/$foo/` is taking a regular expression (whatever the value of `$foo`), finding it in the file. The `d` tells it to delete the line.

`sed` doesn't usually do an *in place* edit. You usually have to write to another file and then to a move. However, some `sed` commands may have such a parameter. You can check your manage.

---

### Second Try

> I think it must take some action or perform some processing or something, and one of its effects is that one of the $foos is gone. (But I could be wrong.) –  ruakh yesterday

This is what I get answering these questions at night.

You can take advantage of the fact that `grep` returns *true* (i.e. exit value = 0) if it can find your regular expression and *false* (i.e. exit value not equal to 0) otherwise:

```
while grep -o -q "$foo" "/some/file"
do
    some_command_that_deletes_foo_in_file
done
```

The `-q` tells grep not to output anything. Instead, the exit value of `grep` will be *true* if the string is found and *false* if it isn't.

Read your manpage on `grep`. Some `grep` commands don't have the `-q` parameter. In that case, you'l need to redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to `/dev/null`.

Another tact may be to do your count of the number of lines, and then use that as a counter:

```
count=$(grep -o "$foo" "/some/file" | wc -w)  # $(...) is the preferred syntax over `...`

for loop in {1..$count}
do
    some_command_that_deletes_foo_in_file
done
```

The advantage is that you only grep through the file once (which maybe a long operation). However, your count maybe incorrect if `$foo` is on more than one line.

A few notes:

- The `$(...)` is preferred over backticks
- When you set a variable, you don't use the dollar sign in front of that variable. Note I have `count=` and not `$count=`.
- Watch spaces. `count= $(...)` is wrong because there's a space after the equals sign.

Comment: The OP's explanation, "Each time that command is run, there is one less instance of $foo in that file", doesn't suggest to me that it *merely* removes an instance of `$foo`; rather, I think it must take some action or perform some processing or something, and one of its effects is that one of the `$foo`s is gone. (But I could be wrong.)